# Why are second and third excluded from balk rule?

Tags: baseball

Looking up the balk rules in baseball, I came across this line:

> steps or feints from the rubber to first base without completing the throw

Why only first base? Why are second and third excluded from this?

Comment: Can you provide the exact rule you are quoting, preferably with a link? I don't find that particular wording in the official rules, and there are quite a few parts to the definition. Most of them don't apply to a specific base or bases.